# Convert url with method name to original page url

Tags: tapestry

Does Tapestry have some utility method that converts url like

```
http://localhost:8080/page1.component:method?t:ac=contextParameterId
```

to original page url like

```
http://localhost:8080/page1/contextParameterId
```

Answer (score 1):

The first url fires a specific event on a page

The second is a normal page url

Both have an activation context.

They are not equivalent, they do different things and hence there is not a conversion from one to the other.

Without more info it's difficult to know what you're asking. I'm just guessing here but perhaps you are seeing tapestry redirect to the normal page url after firing the event.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After login I want to redirect to last page. But my last request that initiated login is post request like in first url. I just want to redirect to my last page before login with normal page url without post data

Comment: Your login page will need to know the "target" page. You can either pass this in the activation context (preferred) or use the session. More info [here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/state/passingdatabetweenpages) and [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/page-navigation.html)

Comment: My question was in how to covert first form to second. Does Tapestry have some util class for that?

Comment: Tapestry does not convert one to another!!!! The first is an event which was probably generated by an event link. Depending on what was returned from the event, tapestry will redirect accordingly. In your example, I'm guessing a page instance was returned from the event which had an activation context set.